# Kendo UI Grid Update button not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing a KendoUI Grid with Inline editable option in javascript and can't make Update button to fire click event and post the data to server side update event. Clicking on Update button won't even update the grid on client.

Hope someone can help me point out what I am doing wrong here.

This is not a duplicate to this as I have tired the jfiddle link in the answer and it is not working too.
[kendo UI grid update function wont fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750493/kendo-ui-grid-update-function-wont-fire)

```
<div id="grid"></div>

 @section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "Home/GetPupilsAsJson",
                    dataType: 'json'
                },                    
                update: {
                    url: "Home/UpdatePupils",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            autoSync: true                
        });

        $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            editable: "inline",
            pageable: true,
            columns: [{
                field: "Id",
                title: "Id",
                width: 150,
                hidden: true
            }, {
                field: "Firstname",
                title: "Firstname",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "Lastname",
                title: "Lastname",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "DateOfBirth",
                title: "DateOfBirth",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "Class",
                title: "Class",
                width: 150
            }, {
                field: "Year",
                title: "Year",
                width: 150
            },
            {
                command: ["edit"],
                width: 150
            }]
        });       
    });
</script>    
 }
```

HomeController

```
 public ActionResult GetPupilsAsJson()
    {            
        return Json(GetPupils(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [HttpPost]
    public void UpdatePupils(Pupil p)
    {
          //never reach here
    }
```

Comment: Can you please try without parameter 'Pupil p' in UpdatePupils and tell me program reached there or not?

Comment: @MustafaP .. I tired as you suggested and still doesn't work. In fact, my problem is Update button doesn't even close Edit fields on client. I tried with MVC wrapper it works fine but we don't have license for the wrapper unfortunately.

Comment: If you have your browser in `Developer Mode` or `inspection` and you check for network traffic, do you see any request to you see the request going thru? I mean, is your browser calling `Home/UpdatePupils`?

Comment: @OnaBai There is no request firing from Kendo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why but fixed it by putting schema information.

```
schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Firstname: { editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
                Lastname: { validation: { required: true } },
                DateOfBirth: { validation: { required: true } },
                Class: { validation: { required: true } },
                Year: { validation: { required: true } }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, if you have a kendo datasource object, seems like you need to specify the schema in order to fire the update function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Url.Action("GetPupilsAsJson", "Home")'` so no need to pass `base url` in your update action like this `BASEURL+ "Home/GetPupilsAsJson"`.

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetPupilsAsJson", "Home")',
                    dataType: 'json'
                },                    
                update: {
                    url:'@Url.Action("UpdatePupils", "Home")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            autoSync: true                
        });
```

Comment: @lawphotog you have any advice to call update and cancel option using Kendo MVC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786267/inline-editing-is-not-working-in-kendo-mvc

Answer (score 0):

use parameter map to pass model values

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetPupilsAsJson", "Home")',,
                    dataType: 'json'
                },                    
                update: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePupils", "Home")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST'
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                   if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                      return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                       }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            autoSync: true                
        });
```

Call Controller with parameterMap

```
public JsonResult UpdatePupils(string models)
        {

            return Json(..);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Is any of your cell text has HTML tags like `<` or `>`, remove them and click on update. The update event will fire.